# pass a parameter into a constructor in a jinternalframe form java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jinternalframe

```
// This is the code in my Home_Page to perform when the jbutton is clicked. 

 private void homeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
 {       
    jDesktopPane1.removeAll();
    error_ e = new error_();
    jDesktopPane1.add(e);
    e.setVisible(true);
    jDesktopPane1.updateUI();
            // TODO add your handling code here:
 }

 //This is the parameter  need to pass through  constructor of jinternalframe form "error_"
 public String eid1;


 Model.JDBC j=new JDBC();
 public error_(String eid) 
 {
    initComponents();
    jLabel3.setText(eid); 
    ResultSet rs;
    try 
    {                     
        rs = j.getData("select mid from employee where eid='"+eid+"'");  

        if(rs.next()==true)
        {
           if(rs.next()==true)
           {
              if(rs.getString(1).equals"sp/cso/it/1")
              {

                    if(eid.equals("sp/cso/it/1"))
                    {}
                    else if(eid.equals("sp/cso/finance/1"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("else if");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("else");
                    }
              }
           }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("outer else executed");
        }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Home_Page.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}

//This is the code in Home_Page to load the jinternalframe form error_ on to the jDesktopPane in Home_Page

private void homeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

      jDesktopPane1.removeAll();
      error_ e = new error_();
      jDesktopPane1.add(e);
      e.setVisible(true);
      jDesktopPane1.updateUI();
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Home_Page is the main jFrame form and there is a jDesktopPane on it.I need to load the jinternaframe form error on to that jDesktoPane when I click the jButton Home on Home_Page.

But there is an error appears in Home_Page when I try to pass the parameter in jinternalframe saying to make a constructor in error_

I did that.In that constructor there is a throw part which throws an exception saying below.

```
debug:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - constructor error_ in class Viewer.error_ cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    at Viewer.Home_Page.homeActionPerformed(Home_Page.java:418)
    at Viewer.Home_Page.access$100(Home_Page.java:33)
    at Viewer.Home_Page$2.actionPerformed(Home_Page.java:166)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Make sure that you've done a "clean and build" operation to make sure you have the latest code compiled. Also, make sure there are no compiler errors before you attempt to run the code

Comment: The error is saying you need to pass in a string to the constructor of _error, but you are just calling new _error();

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try it.